# Problemas con geom_text()

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

Tengo problemas con esa función. ¿Alguien sabe cómo funciona bien?
El problema está cuando quiero poner nombres a la etiquetas u otro tipo de datos de texto a la gráfica.

```
t2<- ggplot(f, aes(x = n, y = GT)) +    
  geom_col(fill = "gray70") +    
  ## add percentage labels    
  geom_text(aes(label = perc)) +    
  theme_minimal()
```

t2

El resultado es: Error in `geom_text()`:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 2nd layer.
Caused by error in `FUN()`:
! object 'perc' not found
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

¿Por qué?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Por favor agrega la salida del comando `str(f)` para poder entender dónde esta el problema.